# \hhline doesn't work

Tags: tables, rules

I wonder if you can help me why LaTeX can't draw a `\hhline` in my table?

(I would put a picture but I need at least 10 reputation...)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{palatino, url, multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}  
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Rok} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$r_f$}\\
    \hhline{~--}
      & ARAD & INFA\\
    \hline
      2000         & 7,38 \%  & \\
    \hline
      2001    & 5,43 \% & \\
    \hline
      2002         & 4,15 \%  &  \\
    \hline
      2003    & 4,82 \% & \\
    \hline
      2004         & 4,04 \% & \\
    \hline
      2005         & 3,61 \% &\\
    \hline
      2006         & 3,68 \% & \\
    \hline
      2007         & 4,65 \%  &  4,28 \%\\
    \hline
      2008    & 4,09 \% & 4,55 \%\\
    \hline
      2009         & 3,68 \% & 4,67 \%\\
    \hline
      2010         & 3,75 \% & 3,71 \%\\
    \hline
      2011         & 3,43 \% & 3,51 \%\\
    \hline
      2012         & 1,45 \% & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Hrubý výnos českého desetiletého dluhopisu v letech 2000 - 2012, zdroj: ČNB a MPO}\label{dluhopisy}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of code]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It's important to know what packages are needed, in order to avoid having to guess.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `czech` option to `babel` is giving a different meaning to `-`, so you need to turn this shorthand off before using the `\hhline` command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{here}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
    \centering\shorthandoff{-}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Rok} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$r_f$}\\
    \hhline{~--}
      & ARAD & INFA\\
    \hline
      2000         & 7,38 \%  & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Hrubý výnos českého desetiletého dluhopisu v letech 2000 - 2012, zdroj: ČNB a MPO}\label{dluhopisy}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (please always post complete documents). Note you should avoid using `[H]` as much as possible as it defeats the point of the LaTeX table float mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline,multirow,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Rok} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$r_f$}\\
    \hhline{~--}
      & ARAD & INFA\\
    \hline
      2000         & 7,38 \%  & \\
    \hline
      2001    & 5,43 \% & \\
    \hline
      2002         & 4,15 \%  &  \\
    \hline
      2003    & 4,82 \% & \\
    \hline
      2004         & 4,04 \% & \\
    \hline
      2005         & 3,61 \% &\\
    \hline
      2006         & 3,68 \% & \\
    \hline
      2007         & 4,65 \%  &  4,28 \%\\
    \hline
      2008    & 4,09 \% & 4,55 \%\\
    \hline
      2009         & 3,68 \% & 4,67 \%\\
    \hline
      2010         & 3,75 \% & 3,71 \%\\
    \hline
      2011         & 3,43 \% & 3,51 \%\\
    \hline
      2012         & 1,45 \% & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Hrubý výnos českého desetiletého dluhopisu v letech 2000 - 2012, zdroj: ČNB a MPO}\label{dluhopisy}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```